# Bind Drop Down list using query in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind drop dawn list using jquery depends on another ddl  i am using jquery with mvc and here is the code i am using :

```
 public IList<Categories> GetProductCategories(int ProductID, int Inst)
        {
           //items is a list get it some way no need for details 


                return items;
            }
        }
```

and here is the jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#ddlProductType').change(function () {
        var x = $('#ddlInstallation').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetProductCategories',
            data: { ProductID: $(this).val(), Inst: x },
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value='" + data[x].Value + "'>" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $('#ddlCategory').html(markup).show();
            }
        });
    });
)};
```

any help :)

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: the problem was it do not bid the ddl but i found an answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution First all I need is not to use it as a function you can do the following :

```
  public JsonResult GetProductCategories(int ProductID, int Inst)
        {
                //items is your list what ever how you get it 
                JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
                result.Data = items;
                return result;
            }
```

and there is no errors in  your jquery code just try

Comment: I try it and it works json result is better and easy for my case i found an article for the same questions too  thanks